# Save input search history

Tags: javascript, input

i have input and search button, i want that when i click input show values which i searched before. and when i click button save new value in history how can i do this?  here is what i tried but does not do anything. thanks

HTML:

```
<input class="inp" type="text">
<button class="search"></button>
```

JS:

```
    let dd = document.querySelector('.inp').value;
    document.querySelector('.inp').name = dd;
```

Comment: Save it in an `array` and loop through it when you want show old search results

Comment: You can also use localStorage to save it long-term.

Comment: Consider using a library for this type as there is **alottttt** of work involved in using `input` as all previous `search history` holder. because that input need to work like a dropdown which hold all previous searches you performed.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Can't you just use the `list` attribute?

Comment: @ObsoleteAwareProduce so many ways but some work involved, I am throwing ideas here to help the OP.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```html
<input class="inp" type="text" list="searchdata">
<button class="search">Search</button>
<datalist id="searchdata"></datalist>
```

Script:

```js
var searchHistory = (localStorage.searchHistory) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.searchHistory) : [];
document.querySelector(".search").addEventListener("click", () => {
  searchHistory.push(document.querySelector(".inp").value);
  localStorage.searchHistory = JSON.stringify(searchHistory);
});
document.querySelector(".inp").addEventListener("focus", () => {
  var data = document.querySelector("datalist#searchdata");
  data.innerHTML = "";
  searchHistory.forEach((search) => {
    data.innerHTML = "<option>" + data.innerHTML;
    data.querySelector("option").innerText = search;
  });
});
```